# Gwt and Sencha, did you forget yo inherit a required module.

Tags: java, gwt, extjs

I am trying to implement a BarChart in GWT 2.6 using Sencha GXT 3.1 beta.
It compiles fine but i do get several

14:40:40.102 [ERROR] [comav200] Line 71: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Errors. I do use the import com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart; (and several more).
Anyone has any thoughts on why this occur or what i have forgotten?

Best regards,
Kerrai

Comment: I don't know Sencha but maybe there's a module like, maybe, `com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart` (following GWT's naming conventions) that you forgot to `<inherit>` in your `gwt.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please validate below `inherits` in `gwt.xml`

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart' />
```

For detailed information and basic chart example please have a look at

**[Getting started with GXT charts](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/charts/GettingStartedCharts.html)**

---

*Copied form the above link if you don't want to go to the link.*

**Project module setup**

Using charts requires a library be added to the GWT project xml module.

Add `com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart` to the GWT project module:

```
  <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart' />
```

`Project.gwt.xml` module example: (*This is a complete example and much of this is optional.*)

Please validate your `gwt.xml`

```
  <!-- Project.gwt.xml module file -->
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
    "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
  <module rename-to='project'>
      <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
      <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

      <!-- Other module inherits -->
      <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />

      <!-- Add this for using GXT charts -->
      <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart' />

      <!-- GXT Stylesheet -->
      <stylesheet src="reset.css" />

      <!-- Override the blue theme -->
      <inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.theme.gray.Gray" />

      <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
      <entry-point class='com.sencha.gxt.project.client.ProjectEntryPoint' />

      <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
      <source path='client' />
      <source path='shared' />
  </module>
```